# How to delete/erase a specific polygon in openGL?

Tags: opengl

Suppose i have drawn a triangle,a cube,a square using draw_triangle,draw_cube and draw_square function respectively.How can I delete a cube using keypress func.?..If i use glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) entire screen will be erased..How to delete a specific polygon.?

Comment: Suppose there was a way to delete a specific polygon after it was drawn. What would appear in its place? The information of "what used to be there" is long gone.

Answer (score 6):

> How to delete a specific polygon.?

Don't render it in next frame.

Once you draw a polygon, there is no polygon, just a bunch of pixels in color buffer + values in depth buffer. So you can't "delete" it, and you can't restore previous state of color/depth buffer. So clear screen, redraw the scene without polygon you didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear only a specific part of the screen or any specific image, then redisplay it by using a keyboard interrupt wihout clearing the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to have a boolean variable which indicates whether your object must be displayed or not. Thus, **only** when a key is pressed, you clear the screen and redraw the entire scene.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like that:

```
Render()
{
 clear_screen();

 setup_camera_and_other_scene_states();

 if (cube) drawCube();

 if (sphere) drawSphere();

 swap_buffers():
}

keyPress()
{
 if (presses_some_key) cube = !cube;
}
```